# Full text in UIAlertView not shown correctly in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uialertview

In `iOS SDK 7` I was displaying a message while I was loading some data in this way:

```
myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [myAlertView setMessage:@"long text...."];
    alertView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 70.0);

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 150, 90, 90)];

    [indicator startAnimating];
    [myAlertView indicator ];
    [myAlertView show];
    [indicator release];
    [myAlertView release];
```

All the message was shown correctly with ALL the text. in `SDK 8 (beta)` it only display first 2 lines. I have space for it in the box, but the text is like cutted. I tried changing the `Frame` size:

```
CGRectMake(130, 110, 50, 50)
```

but nothing help.

Any ideas how to fix it for `iOS 8` ?

Comment: You should never alter the size of the `UIAlertView`, this will be done by `UIAlertView` depending on the test size. If the text is too long a scrollable view is automatically presented. I'm guessing you are adding the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to the `UIAlertView` which is not supported by the iOS SDK as stated in the `UIAlertView` documentation. Also iOS 8 is not longer BETA, use the GM to test your app.

Comment: if I remove the line : `alertView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 70.0);` It still not showing the full text

Comment: Are you still adding the `UIActivityIndicatorView` because that is not possible.

Comment: Strange I'm using the last beta version and I don't getting those results

Comment: iOS 8 is released (GM - Gold Master) so don't use a beta version.

Comment: It fixed in the iOS 8 GM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its also working fine in ios 8. @rckoenes is right plz Use ios8 GM.

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[myAlertView setMessage:@"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. End"];
[myAlertView show];
```

See here

[image]